# I'm getting an undefined error in my project made with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending as a prop an array of objects. When I `console.log(this.props)` I get the array of objects, but when I try to assign it to a variable it gives me

> TypeError:ninjas is undefined

This is how i send the prop

```
import React from 'react';
import Ninjas from './Ninjas';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ninjas:[
      {name:"Ryu",age:"20",belt:"black",key:"1"},
      {name:"Yoshi",age:"22",belt:"yellow",key:"2"},
      {name:"Mario",age:"25",belt:"white",key:"1"}
    ]
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My first React App</h1>
      <Ninjas list={ this.state.ninjas }/>
    </div>
  )
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is how i recibe it

```
import React from 'react';

class Ninjas extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const { ninjas } = this.props;
        const ninjasList = ninjas.map(ninja => {
            return(
                <div className="ninja" key={ ninja.key }>
                <div>Name: { ninja.name }</div>
                <div>Age: { ninja.age }</div>
                <div>Belt: { ninja.belt }</div>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="ninja-list">
                { ninjasList }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Ninjas;
```

Comment: What is the name of prop that has array in this.props???

Comment: can you please show the code where you are passing ninjas and calling the component. Without that code it is not understandable.

Comment: In render method use const ninjas = {this.props.list};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `ninjas` in your Ninjas component `<Ninjas list={ this.state.ninjas }/>` using list props. So, you should be using this `const { list } = this.props;` instead of `const { ninjas } = this.props;` in your Ninjas Component.

```
import React from 'react';

class Ninjas extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const { list } = this.props;
        const ninjasList = list.map(ninja => {
            return(
                <div className="ninja" key={ ninja.key }>
                <div>Name: { ninja.name }</div>
                <div>Age: { ninja.age }</div>
                <div>Belt: { ninja.belt }</div>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="ninja-list">
                { ninjasList }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Ninjas;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Ninjas list={ this.state.ninjas }/>
```

I suggest you change this to

```
<Ninjas ninjas={ this.state.ninjas }/>
```

Otherwise the name would be `list` in your child component.

In other words the name of the property you use when rendering the component (here in the `render` function of `App`) has to correspond to the name you get from the `props` object in your child component (here your child component is `Ninjas`).

Comment: thanks for the answer!, but if i do that, then im not resolving my main problem that is to recieve the prop as an array and map it so i can assign it to a new list

Comment: In render method use const ninjas = {this.props.list};

Comment: @JuanPedroPontVergés see my updated answer based on your edit